# Inserting record to connected table on signup()

Tags: backand

Imagine two tables,  users and addresses. addresses is connected to users via a one-to-many relationship.

I would like to add records to addresses table on signup()

```
signup(firstName, lastName, email, {'what should I be' : 'what should I be'})
```

Does it have to be done using signup parameters? or there are other ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use 2 methods for that:**

1) using Back& Actions - server side logic, after you create your user signup.

2) using your code like:

```
this.backand.signup(firstName, lastName, email)
  .then((data: any) => {
    console.log('Sign up succeeded');
    //Do here the Address thing to update the addrss table...
  },
  (err: any) => {
    console.log(err)
  }
);
```

Comment: "//Do here the Address thing to update the addrss table..." Meaning you can run an update to the address table as you want.

You can start learning here [link](https://www.backand.com/app-examples) & here [link](http://docs.backand.com/)